# Fixing Debian Dependency Package Database

Tags: dependencies, debian, dpkg

I seem to have managed to completely mess up my Debian server. It's important to note I'm not very good with Debian and find myself completely out my league with this issue.

Getting on with it, below is a screenshot of the error from running:
    apt-get -f install

It all came from me trying to install Python3.5 and no has gotten to this mess.

[image: Error from apt-get -f install]

Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

**Edit:** Following from Jamil Said's response:

[image]

**Edit:** Following Jamil Said's edit I used dpkg --purge --force-all to remove some problematic packages and then removed the test source before apt-get update.

Had to ensure I reinstalled the kernel though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you **reboot your computer first** and then run the code below (note: it will run a deep update known as "dist-upgrade"):

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg --configure -a
sleep 1
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install -f
sleep 1
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg --configure -a
sleep 1
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y update
sleep 1
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

And if it runs well, reboot the computer again at the end.

**Edit**: if that doesn't work, we are entering dangerous territory. Here's a suggestion on how to proceed: locate the file /var/log/apt/term.log, peruse through it and remove any file listed as "broken". Also, go through your terminal messages and take note of all packages that the system complains about and remove them. You can remove those packages by running this as root:

```
apt-get remove <package>
```

After that, reboot the computer and rerun the commands I first gave on this post, and after that, reboot and try to reinstall the offending packages (if there's a compatibility problem, apt-get should resolve it or alert you to it).

Comment: Thanks for your help, after running these commands I'm still getting the issue of packages having unmet dependencies. I've edited the question to show the outcome.

Comment: Same end result. Each command exits early from too many errors.

Comment: Your edit got me on right lines and I was eventually able to get back to a stable system, thanks a lot!